# Response 401 with python requests

Tags: python-requests

```
import requests

token = {
    "access_token": "q3eFsG5ONt6fvdJsB3AAXL38KBAwrdCJ0",
    "api_server": "https:\/\/api07.iq.questrade.com\/",
    "expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "Y3p43laee75kfDxzDWrONoNpkhgAFUyb0",
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}

uri = "https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/markets"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token.get('access_token'))}

rt = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)
response = rt.json()
```

I do not understand what is happening here because `token` is updated, but I got `<Response [401]>`. What do I need to do to fix the problem?

Comment: `https:\/\/api07.iq.questrade.com\/` - Maybe make this valid?

Comment: You're getting an API specific err status code with the response - you should check what it means in their docs.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 `uri = "{}/v1/markets".format(token.get('api_server'))` gave me `requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: https:\` .   `uri` gave me `'https:\\/\\/api02.iq.questrade.com\\//v1/markets'`

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 means `Unauthorized`

Comment: `https://api07.iq.questrade.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
"api_server": "https:\/\/api07.iq.questrade.com\/"
```

You have `\/`, you should use the usual one:

```
"api_server": "https://api07.iq.questrade.com/"
```